# contenteditable div with 'text-align: right' in IE8 doesn't show caret

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, contenteditable

I'm creating a contentEditable div within a table cell to capture user input. The problem is, when I align the text to the right IE8 does not show a text input caret. Every other browser I've tried works. It works if I don't use "text-align: right". It also works if the caret is anywhere other than the far right of the div. Here's some sample code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table width=400 border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div contentEditable=true style='outline: none; text-align: right;'>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? If nothing, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right padding fixed the problem.

Comment: I want to extend the scope of the question: the same error occures with **any input field**: 'text-align: right' in IE8 doesn't show cursor. +1 for Sparafusile's answer: 'padding-right: 1px;' fixes the glitch but appearance still differs from other browsers by 1px.